# File upload in specific folder of web application in liferay..?

Tags: file-upload, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am using liferay 6.0.5. I am uploading file using following code.

```java
UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
String submissionFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName("file");//uploaded filename
File submissionFile = uploadRequest.getFile("file");
```

this works fine and upload file in tomcat's temp directory with some different name. What I want is.."There is one folder docs in my project directory. I want uploaded file in this directory". How to do this in liferay..?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the temp directory for the file upload then you can change the following property in portal-ext.properties:

```
com.liferay.portal.upload.UploadServletRequestImpl.temp.dir=C:/MyTempDir
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add files to Liferay's Document Library then check out the following classes:

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.html

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/service/DLFolderLocalServiceUtil.html