# how to store image path in mySql from jsp file using liferay?

Tags: java, mysql, image, jsp, liferay

Hello I'm using liferay portlets.  I want to store image path in MySQL using jspfile and using that imagepath I want to display image on another jsp file. How can this be done?

upload.jsp:

```
<aui:input type="file" label="Photo" name="photo"/>
```

using java file I store my image in database. By following code I try to store image in MySQL.

```
String photo=ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"photo"); 
directory d1 = new directoryImpl();
d1.setPhoto(photo);
```

and using following code I try to retrieve image on another jsp page.

```
  <% 
  int count = directoryLocalServiceUtil.getdirectoriesCount();
  List<directory> tlist=directoryLocalServiceUtil.getdirectories(0,count);
  %>
  <%
  for(directory dd:tlist)
  {
  %>
  <%=dd.getPhoto() %>
  <%
   }
   %>
```

but this store image name in database field.(i.e `images.jpg`). When I retrieve from database I can retrieve only `images.jpg`.

How can I save and retrieve an image on another page?

Comment: Without knowing JSP, I assume by calling `String photo = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"photo");` you will only get the name of the file in the input but never it's data! Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922463/file-upload-in-specific-folder-of-web-application-in-liferay might help you.

Comment: hello where should i write this code? in java file? then how to retrieve from database tell me

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to store image path in database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942044/how-to-store-image-path-in-database)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, here is my solution if you are using the document library

```
 ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay)renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);

try {
    FileEntry fileEntry = DLAppServiceUtil.getFileEntry(themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroupId(), 0, "test1.jpg");
    imagePath = DLUtil.getWebDavURL(themeDisplay, fileEntry.getFolder(), fileEntry);
    previewImagePath = DLUtil.getPreviewURL(fileEntry, fileEntry.getFileVersion(), themeDisplay, "");
} catch (PortalException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```