# how to store image path in database?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, file-upload, liferay

hello i am making employee directory.in that form i want to upload photo of employee,when i try to store image i got error like  **Portlet is temporarily unavailable** if i remove logic of image upload then my other data store in database sucessfully. kindly help me how to store image path in database. i have create **images**  folder in **/webapps**. i want to store my all image in this folder and store my image path into database. please tell me how to store image path and after storing image path how to display image in other page.

Here i am giving you my java code where i have write my logic.
     package com.dir;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.dir.model.directory;
import com.dir.model.impl.directoryImpl;
import com.dir.service.directoryLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.counter.service.CounterLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.upload.UploadPortletRequest;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FileUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;


  public class Directory extends MVCPortlet {

public void updatedir(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse  
 actionResponse)throws IOException, PortletException
        {
String empname =ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"empname");
    String designation =ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"designation");
String qualification =ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"qualification");
    String email =ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"email");
String photo=ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"photo");
String company =ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"company");
int experiance=ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest,"experiance");

directory d1 = new directoryImpl();

// set primary key
long directoryId=0L;
try
{

     directoryId=CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(this.getClass().getName());
} 
catch (SystemException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
   d1.setDirectoryId(directoryId);

        // set UI fields
        d1.setEmpname(empname);
        d1.setDesignation(designation);
        d1.setQualification(qualification);
        d1.setEmail(email);
        d1.setPhoto(photo);
        d1.setCompany(company);
        d1.setExperiance(experiance);

    File file;

        UploadPortletRequestupreq=PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(actionRequest);
    file=upreq.getFile(photo);

    Stringpath=actionRequest.getPortletSession().getPortletContext().getRealPath(photo) 
     + "//" + ("/images");

        File fileone= new File(path);
        FileUtil.copyDirectory(file,fileone);

        // set audit field(s)
        d1.setDateAdded(new Date());

        // insert the book using persistence api
        try {

        directoryLocalServiceUtil.adddirectory(d1);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }


      }
```

here I am Giving u my Jsp file from where i upload photo.

```
   <aui:form name="fm" method="POST" action="<%= updatedirURL.toString() %>"   
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <aui:input name="empname" label="Name"/>

 <aui:input name="designation" label="Designation"/>
 <aui:input name="qualification" label="Qualification"/>

 <aui:input name="email" label="Email"/>

 <aui:input type="file" label="Photo" name="photo"/>

 <aui:input name="company" label="Company"/>

 <aui:input name="experiance" label="Experiance"/>

 <aui:button type="submit" value="Save"/>
 </aui:form>
```

kindly help me where i am wrong and which thing is missing its required. and also tell me how to display data from that folder.

Comment: You cannot just assign a file upload to a String and assume that filename and binary content go through. Indeed, they don't. You'll find multiple examples of code if you search for "liferay upload" - and you might even want to learn how uploads work in the servlet world to grasp the concept

Answer (score 0):

view this [tuorial](http://codeglobe.blogspot.in/2009/03/readwrite-blob-fromto-mysql-in-java_21.html) regarding the file(the file may be any type) read/write using mysql,Tt will helps you much..
Cheer...

Comment: sundar G kindly tell me which thing is missing in my code please